# Python3.4 + Pillow:

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-3.4

I installed PIL / Pillow by using:

```
easy_install pillow
```

And then imported the library:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
```

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/temp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from bot import Bot   File "C:/temp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from PIL import ImageGrab, Image   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-4.1.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\PIL\ImageGrab.py",
> line 18, in <module>   File
> "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-4.1.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\PIL\Image.py",
> line 56, in <module>   File
> "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-4.1.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\PIL\_imaging.py",
> line 7, in <module>   File
> "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-4.1.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\PIL\_imaging.py",
> line 3, in __bootstrap__   File
> "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 21, in <module>
>     import imp   File "C:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 22, in <module>
>     from importlib import util   File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\util.py", line 12, in <module>
>     from contextlib import contextmanager   File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 5, in <module>
>     from functools import wraps   File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 22, in <module>
>     from types import MappingProxyType, MethodType ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

I'm getting the same behaviour on different computers

Comment: from where are you running the file? and where is the file saved?

Comment: I simply created a main.py in a temporary folder and run it with `python main.py`

Comment: uninstall pillow and install using pip install pillow and check again